# How to STOP iPad PRO simulator from using stretching iPad Air 2 simulator

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, appdelegate, uiscreen

i use Objective-C for my Xcode. In Xcode 7.1, I created a new iPadPRO.h and iPadPRO.m files and ipadPRO.storyboard. I connected the storyboard classes in identity inspector with the appropriate .h and .m files. I don't use auto layout/size classes for this app.

in AppDelegate.m I used..

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2)
        {
        UIStoryboard *Retina = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Retina" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialViewController =[Retina instantiateInitialViewController];

            self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }

    }
```

Is there a separate code or an addition to the above code that I can use so the iPad PRO simulator doesn't use stretched iPad Air 2 code/images and instead uses its own that i'll create for it?